# IP Canonicalization Fails Test

Tags: apache

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.manderplumbing.co.nz$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.manderplumbing.co.nz/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^222\.154\.54\.44
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.manderplumbing.co.nz/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
```

This fails the IP Canonicalization Test
but have I got this wrong.  The first rewriteC&R rules meet URL Canonicalization

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, especially what "IP Canonicalization Test" you are talking about.

Comment: Unless there is a reason for it, I would make the second Rule exactly the same as the first. Readers get confused if they dont see why there is a difference (missing ^$ and RL/LR).

Comment: SEO Sitecheckup IP Canonicalization Test.  Some suggest this is not necessary.

Comment: If you mean this: http://seositecheckup.com/ then there is a "explain" button. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second condition is never checked, as it already matches the first one (not the hostname).

Comment: Tried making second rule same as first but SEO Test failed.